# Submit button cancel

Tags: internet-explorer, http, google-chrome, firefox, browser

Let me start by saying I'm not a web guy.  We have an html form with a submit button on it and also an onClicked event defined.  The onClicked event just does data validation on a few fields.

In ie,  when the button is clicked twice, it seems like the first request is canceled and it's connection severed.

In Firefox, when the button is clicked twice, it seem like the first request is completed and the second request never happens.

In Chrome, when the button is clicked twice, the first request completes but in the background and doesn't load in the browser but instead the result of the second request is what is displayed to the user.

Another interesting twist, if I have fiddler running, than IE exhibits the same behavior as Chrome.

Can anybody explain this behavior to me?  Or at least tell me if the way I described it is how it is actually working?

Comment: Can you maybe post some of the code (the form and the validation js) ?

Comment: I am actually unable to post the code as it belongs to a client of ours.  This is more of a general question about browser behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ocourse i can feel your pain ,but It depends on browsers.

I too had the pain .But instead of going through all those things (If you are interested,that's OK) I fixed it  by handling the submit button properly .

When user clicks on `submit` button first time ..I disable the button and if my validate function returns true,The form will submit .

Otherwise  I'll enable the `submit`  button again .

This is what i am doing for my all forms to get rid of the Distinct behaviors of our `TOP BROWSERS` .

Comment: This is actually our clients website and that is the advice we gave them.  The underlying issue is that there clients are getting their credit card dinged twice and we think this might be the cause.  Although there was one report of it on either FireFox or Chrome (we apparently only track if it is IE or not IE).  So I'm not sure if there is another issue going on here or not.  But I think your comment has confirmed my suspicions that the browsers are all behaving differently.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `submit` event for your form validation instead of `onClick`.
[It is consistent across all browsers](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/submit.html), and is triggered even if the user submit the form using the enter key.

[jQuery `submit` event doc](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  We actually aren't in control of the website.  Only the api.